# Maven build profiler per user

Tags: java, maven

Where do I need to configure build profile per user?

If the answer is under `%USER_HOME%/.m2/settings.xml` then do we need to create the `setting.xml` manually in the mentioned path? I do not find one.

[image]

Maven version: 3.3.9.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Yes, you need to create the `settings.xml` file](https://maven.apache.org/settings.html).

> There are two locations where a `settings.xml` file may live:
>
> - The Maven install: `$M2_HOME/conf/settings.xml`
> - A user’s install: `${user.home}/.m2/settings.xml`

This file is not part of the Maven installation and is part of the user configuration so this file must be created by hand.

Note that, still quoting from the reference:

> Tip: If you need to create user-specific settings from scratch, it’s easiest to copy the global settings from your Maven installation to your `${user.home}/.m2` directory. Maven’s default `settings.xml` is a template with comments and examples so you can quickly tweak it to match your needs.

so you can just copy the one present in your Maven installation and tweak it.

Comment: @tanuki, great explanation. Are you interesting in improving the Maven documentation directly? Contact me through SF.net or my Apache profile.